# Sort items in an array by more than one field with lodash

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

How can I sort an array of objects by more then one field using lodash. So for an array like this:

```
[
  {a: 'a', b: 2},
  {a: 'a', b: 1},
  {a: 'b', b: 5},
  {a: 'a', b: 3},
]
```

I would expect this result

```
[
  {a: 'a', b: 1},
  {a: 'a', b: 2},
  {a: 'a', b: 3},
  {a: 'b', b: 5},
]
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This is much easier in a current version of lodash (2.4.1).  You can just do this:

```
var data = [
    {a: 'a', b: 2},
    {a: 'a', b: 1},
    {a: 'b', b: 5},
    {a: 'a', b: 3},
];

data = _.sortBy(data, ["a", "b"]);  //key point: Passing in an array of key names

_.map(data, function(element) {console.log(element.a + " " + element.b);});
```

And it will output this to the console:

```
"a 1"
"a 2"
"a 3"
"b 5"
```

*Warning: See the comments below. This looks like it was briefly called `sortByAll` in version 3, but now it's back to [`sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy) instead.*

Comment: This does not work as of v3.0.0.  The syntax is correct but the method to use is  `_.sortByAll(data, ["a", "b"]);`  The difference between `_.sortBy` and `_.sortByAll` is `_.sortBy` sorts off of an iteratee and `_.sortByAll` sorts by property names. [api reference](https://lodash.com/docs#sortByAll) and [changelog](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Changelog#v300)

Comment: _.sortByAll no longer exists in v4.0.

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Changelog

Comment: `_.sortByAll` works great in 3.10. In 4.0+ use `_.sortBy`. Thanks!

Comment: You can also add third parameter (order direction) like `_.orderBy(collection, ['fieldA', 'fieldB'], ['asc', 'desc']);`