# How can I use lodash/underscore to sort by multiple nested fields?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I want to do something like this:

```
var data = [
    {
        sortData: {a: 'a', b: 2}
    },
    {
        sortData: {a: 'a', b: 1}
    },
    {
        sortData: {a: 'b', b: 5}
    },
    {
        sortData: {a: 'a', b: 3}
    }
];

data = _.sortBy(data, ["sortData.a", "sortData.b"]);

_.map(data, function(element) {console.log(element.sortData.a + " " + element.sortData.b);});
```

And have it output this:

```
"a 1"
"a 2"
"a 3"
"b 5"
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work and the array remains sorted in its original form.  [This would work if the fields weren't nested inside the `sortData`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24111473/61624)  How can I use lodash/underscore to sort an array of objects by more than one nested field?

I've turned this into a lodash feature request: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/581

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a `_.sortByAll` method in lodash version 3:

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/3.10.1/doc/README.md#_sortbyallcollection-iteratees

Lodash version 4, it has been unified:

https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy

Other option would be to sort values yourself:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```
function compareValues(v1, v2) {
    return (v1 > v2) 
        ? 1 
        : (v1 < v2 ? -1 : 0);
};


var data = [
    { a: 2, b: 1 },
    { a: 2, b: 2 },
    { a: 1, b: 3 }
];

data.sort(function (x, y) {
    var result = compareValues(x.a, y.a);

    return result === 0 
        ? compareValues(x.b, y.b) 
        : result;
});

// data after sort:
// [
//     { a: 1, b: 3 },
//     { a: 2, b: 1 },
//     { a: 2, b: 2 }
// ];
```

Answer (score 47):

**Update:** See the comments below, this is not a good solution in most cases.

---

Someone kindly answered [in the issue I created](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/581).  Here's his answer, inlined:

```
_.sortBy(data, function(item) {
   return [item.sortData.a, item.sortData.b];
});
```

I didn't realize that you're allowed to *return* an array from that function.  The documentation doesn't mention that.

Comment: This is because when you return an array it is converted to string and then compared, but if your second item is number and you want to sort by that second value as number, it would not work.

Comment: Tomas called out an important edge case. Use _.orderBy as suggested by kenjiru, or _.sortBy with the correct syntax a la Tomas

Answer (score 44):

If you need to specify the sort direction, you can use `_.orderBy` with the array of functions syntax from **Lodash 4.x**:

```
_.orderBy(data, [
  function (item) { return item.sortData.a; },
  function (item) { return item.sortData.b; }
], ["asc", "desc"]);
```

This will sort first ascending by property `a`, and for objects that have the same value for property `a`, will sort them descending by property `b`.

It works as expected when the `a` and `b` properties have different types.

Here is a [jsbin example](https://jsbin.com/yegalar/edit?js,console) using this syntax.

Comment: awesome, that answer helped me a lot!

Answer (score 15):

The awesome, simple way is:

```
_.sortBy(data, [function(item) {
    return item.sortData.a;
}, function(item) {
    return item.sortData.b;
}]);
```

I found it from check the source code of lodash, it always check the function one by one.

Hope that help.

Comment: Also, if you want a "reverse" sort for either of those sorting functions, just add a "-" to the value being returned.  `return -item.sortData.a;` for example.

Answer (score 12):

With ES6 easy syntax and lodash

```
sortBy(item.sortData, (item) => (-item.a), (item) => (-item.b))
```

Comment: it is just a negative way to sorting when you do that then yo don't need to reverse the array.

Comment: Beautiful, I love ES6 simplicity!

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work in most cases with underscore:

```
var properties = ["sortData.a", "sortData.b"];
data = _.sortBy(data, function (d) {
    var predicate = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++)
    {
        predicate += (i == properties.length - 1 
                           ? 'd.' + properties[i]
                           : 'd.' + properties[i] + ' + ')
    }
    return eval(predicate)
});
```

[It works and you can see it in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4FT6NGa42k1aKAaVPEFH?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is an integer is converted to a string, add zeroes before the integer to make it have the same length as the longest in the collection:

```
var maxLength = _.reduce(data, function(result, item) {
    var bString = _.toString(item.sortData.b);
    return result > bString.length ? result : bString.length;            
}, 0);

_.sortBy(data, function(item) {
    var bString = _.toString(item.sortData.b);
    if(maxLength > bString.length) {
        bString = [new Array(maxLength - bString.length + 1).join('0'), bString].join('');
    }

    return [item.sortData.a, bString];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a good way to sort array by multiple nested fields.

```
const array = [
{id: '1', name: 'test', properties: { prop1: 'prop', prop2: 'prop'}},
{id: '2', name: 'test2', properties: { prop1: 'prop second', prop2: 'prop second'}}
]
```

I suggest to use 'sorters' object which will describe a key and sort order. It's comfortable to use it with some data table.

```
const sorters = {
 'id': 'asc',
 'properties_prop1': 'desc',//I'm describing nested fields with '_' symbol
}

dataSorted = orderBy(array, Object.keys(sorters).map(sorter => {
    return (row) => {
        if (sorter.includes('_')) { //checking for nested field
            const value = row["properties"][sorter.split('_')[1]];
            return value || null; 
        };
        return row[sorter] || null;// checking for empty values
    };
}), Object.values(sorters));
```

This function will sort an array with multiple nested fields, for the first arguments it takes an array to modify, seconds one it's actually an array of functions, each function have argument that actually an object from 'array' and return a value or null for sorting. Last argument of this function is 'sorting orders', each 'order' links with functions array by index. How the function looks like simple example after mapping:

```
 orderBy(array, [(row)  =>  row[key] || null, (row)  =>  row[key] || null , (row)  =>  row[key] || null] , ['asc', 'desc', 'asc'])
```

P.S. This code can be improved, but I would like to keep it like this for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks, but does this use lodash/underscore?

Comment: Order by method from lodash.